# Can't get data from React-Native-Firebase(v6) Firestore: undefined is not a function (near '...this._firestore.native.collectionGet...')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I've been stuck on this issue for so long. I just started implementing Firestore in my react-native application with react-native-firebase. I'm just following the docs [https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/firestore/quick-start#reading-data] but it doesn't work for me.

This is in Android. Haven't tested in iOS yet.

I keep getting this error:

> `[TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this._firestore.native.collectionGet...')]`

Here's the relevant code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

export default App extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.getData= this.getData.bind(this)
    this.getData()

    this.state = {};
  }

  async getData() {
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
      .collection('Gyms')
      .get() //error with this

      console.log('Documents', querySnapshot.docs);

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @BurningHippo So I just uninstalled/reinstalled the modules, and did a 'react-native run-android' again and now it works. idk man lol

Comment: I am getting the same error. Re-installing module didn't work for me.

Answer (score 18):

This error occurs because the native RNFirestore module is missing.

After `yarn add @react-native-firebase/firestore` you need to run `pod install` and trigger a rebuild with `react-native run-ios`.

edit: installing this modules requires you to re-bundle your application in android as well. run something like `react-native run-android` to do that.

If you are using expo on m1 machine then first cd inside your ios bundle and then run:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue resolves when you re-bundle and restart android dev server

Answer (score 1):

If you have a good firebase / Firestore setup so it's because your queries is false, you can test with something like that:

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

firestore()
  .collection('collection')
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
     console.log(querySnapshot)
  })
```