# Not able to set the data to firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to append some data to my collection('user) with my doc('userName') .set with few datas (phone number, age) (array format).

Here is the code :

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

  firestore()
  .collection('user')
  .doc('userName')
  .set({
    number: '034093434',
    age: 30,
  })
  .then(() => {
    alert('added to firestore');
  });
```

But i am getting error says that :

```
TypeError: this._firestore.native.documentSet is not a. function. (In this._firestore.native.documentSet(this.path,(0,_serialize.buildNativeMap(data), setOptions);' this._firestore.native.documentSet' is undefined)
```

Not sure what i am missing.I followed this doc -> [here](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage).

Each time i will set the new data. so it should add as array (index wise).

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if this is happen in iOS device then kindly do `pod install`

The native `RNFirestore` module is missing so that this error is coming

After yarn `@react-native-firebase/firestore` you need to run `pod install` and trigger a rebuild with `react-native run-ios`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
import import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
```

before

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
```

like this

```
import import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

  firestore()
  .collection('user')
  .doc('userName')
  .set({
    number: '034093434',
    age: 30,
  })
  .then(() => {
    alert('added to firestore');
  });
```

Comment: are you trying adding new document or you already have a document and trying to update?

Comment: i am adding new document

Answer (score 0):

This same error was reported on Github's page and was caused by an incomplete installation of the library. To check for that I wuld suggest to try running:

```
firestore().collection('user').add({a: 'a'})
```

If it returns the same error most likely it's the same issue and could be solved unistalling/reinstalling the library and then running `react-native run-android`
as pointed out in the [Github](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2773#issuecomment-545905266) and this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104680/cant-get-data-from-react-native-firebasev6-firestore-undefined-is-not-a-func) on another thread.

If that doesn't solve the problem I would suggest to report it on Github.

Answer (score 0):

faced same issue in IOS after

```
npm i @react-native-firebase/firestore
```

I run
cd ios & pod install
then
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"
it worked fine