# React Native Firebase integration in IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I faced an issue in firebase integration.

After google login using Firebase, I am gonna to add user data to Firebase Firestore
Google Login using Firebase is working well.

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

export const RegisterUser = async (user) => {
    const userRef = firestore().collection('users');
    await userRef.add({
    uid: user.uid,
        email: user.email,
        name: user.displayName,
        avatar: user.photoURL,
        balance: 1000
    });
}
```

I got this warning.

[image]

As you can see below image, I am not able to manage Firestore now.
I'm not sure if this is the reason for this warning.

[image]

I want to add user data to Firebase Firestore.

I look forward to your reply
Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104680/cant-get-data-from-react-native-firebasev6-firestore-undefined-is-not-a-func) help?

Comment: tomerpacific, thank you. It works now. But what permissions should I request from the client to access Firestore?

Comment: My role is Firebase Admin now.

Comment: Seems like a different question than the one you asked, so I would consider opening another question. Also, a google search might help.